# What is the meaning of 2 variables being dependent?

Tags: probability, independence

When X, Y are dependent random variables, what is the meaning of that dependency?

I am familiar with the definition, however I would like to better understand if and how does this dependency is reflected in the distributions of the random variables.

Answer (score 1):

All independent random variables are independent in the same way. Each pair of dependent random variables - dependent in his particular manner...

And seriously speaking - $X,Y$ are dependent if for some of the realizations of $Y$, the distribution of $X$ conditioned on that is different from its marginal distribution (and vice versa). Knowledge about an event that is connected to one of them might change the distribution of an event that is connected to the other. It is hard to give a more precise answer since the question is very general, so I'll finish with an example:

$X$ is your favorite random variable, $Y=-X$. Clearly, they are dependent. If you know the value of $Y$ you immediately know the value of $X$, while if you don't know the value of $Y$, then $X$ can be any number in its support according to his marginal distribution.